# Did almost all tilapia sold in US undergo sex change?

Tags: nutrition

Taken from this report: [How Tilapia is a More Unhealthy Food Than Bacon](http://www.eatthis.com/tilapia-is-worse-than-bacon).

> *They've Had a Sex Change*
>
> **Virtually all tilapia sold in American supermarkets has undergone a sex change–the result of being fed methyltestosterone during the early, sexless stage of life**. Tilapia pumped full of hormones grow bigger quicker than their natural bros, because they don’t expend energy developing reproductive organs and require less food. Seafood experts consider the effects of methyltestosterone in fish to be insignificant to our health. However, there’s research to suggest the drug can be highly toxic to the liver. In fact, methyltestosterone has been taken off the market in Germany due to its high potential for liver toxicity.

Comment: Interesting and (as often is the case) seemingly misleading conflation of facts/claims. Germany takes methyltestosterone, itself, off the market because of concerns about liver toxicity. What does that have to do with eating meat from fully mature fish that, when they were young/juvenile, were fed methyltestosterone? Not criticizing the question, just noting the direction I anticipate fully-researched answers will go.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - that whole article is... fishy. Pun intended

Comment: Wow, that leap from "sex organ growth repression" to "had a sex change" is making my neck hurt o,o

Answer (score 6):

A quick Web Search turned up an excerpt from [Testosterone: Action, Deficiency, Substitution](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZiZ7MWDqo5oC&pg=PA411&lpg=PA411&dq=methyltestosterone%20germany&source=bl&ots=A4s66e2RTf&sig=imJGJyW1Y-v7hKnfAGo6Oa3MYPQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkoKXzpvXUAhVCcD4KHW6gDbsQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=methyltestosterone%20germany&f=false) (page 410-411).  It did acknowledge the potential negative side-effects of methyltestosterone, and that the appropriate authorities in Germany had ruled that it be removed from the market (where it was being used for medical purposes).  It also noted that the half-life in the blood was approximately 150 minutes, with maximal blood levels 90-120 minutes after ingestion.  As such, it's pretty unlikely that clinically pertinent quantities are making their way to your dinner plate.

A bit more google searching suggests that there have been numerous books written on the subject of tilapia aquaculture, and that a fair number of those books discuss the use of methyltestosterone for the purpose.  It's at least plausible, then, that most of the fish making its way to the supermarket has been so treated, and near-certain that a reasonable percentage has.  There doesn't seem to be a reason to doubt that particular claim.

...and, en fin, it looks like *this particular issue* was a matter of some specific concern, and subject to investigation... in the 1980s.  [Culture of Nonsalmonid Freshwater Fishes, Second Edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=GhHg7npYIKsC&pg=PA98&dq=methyltestosterone%20tilapia%20health&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMzY-6qPXUAhXFGD4KHUkeBQgQ6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q=methyltestosterone%20tilapia%20health&f=false), page 98.  Final conclusion was that the hormone's persistence once it left the gut was minimal, and that it posed no public health concern.

Comment: En fin? I see what you did there.

Answer (score 1):

A found an article from a Brazilian magazine that support this:

> Para turbinar a produtividade, elas recebem uma ração especial à base
>   de cereais (como soja e milho) e hormônios de reversão sexual durante
>   os primeiros 20 dias de vida. Além de garantir aumento de peso, essa
>   alimentação transforma a maior parte da população de peixes em machos
>   – que crescem quase três vezes mais do que as fêmeas.

Translation:

> To boost productivity, they receive a special cereal-based diet (such
>   as soy and corn) and sex reversal hormones during the first 20 days of
>   life. In addition to ensuring weight gain, this feed transforms most
>   of the fish population into males - which grow almost three times more
>   than females.

http://exame.abril.com.br/mundo/por-que-os-ambientalistas-odeiam-a-tilapia/

Edit:
From wikipedia Indonesia created a new specie using genetic engineering:

> Indonesian government research, development and introduced a new
>   species named "genetically supermale Indonesian tilapia" (GESIT).
>   GESIT fish are genetically engineered to hatch eggs that will produce
>   98% - 100% male tilapia. Monosex culture (all male) is more productive
>   and will benefit the farmers. Now, around 14 strains of ikan nila have
>   been developed by contributions from research institutes including
>   MCFAD.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaculture_of_tilapia

Comment: Something published on "Exame" isn't an article by any means. This magazine is a very poor publication that tries very hard to appear a "scientific" magazine, but more often than not fail miserably. It doesn't cite any references to its claims and it is not worth anything more than the original claim.